# Scoping in embedded groovy scripts

Tags: scripting, groovy, scope

In my app, I use Groovy as a scripting language. To make things easier for my customers, I have a global scope where I define helper classes and constants.

Currently, I need to run the script (which builds the global scope) every time a user script is executed:

```
context = setupGroovy();
runScript( context, "global.groovy" ); // Can I avoid doing this step every time?
runScript( context, "user.groovy" );
```

Is there a way to setup this global scope once and just tell the embedded script interpreter: "Look here if you can't find a variable"? That way, I could run the global script once.

Note: Security is not an issue here but if you know a way to make sure the user can't modify the global scope, that's an additional plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the code from `groovy.lang.GroovyShell`: You can precompile the script like so:

```
    GroovyCodeSource gcs = AccessController.doPrivileged( new PrivilegedAction<GroovyCodeSource>() {
        public GroovyCodeSource run() {
            return new GroovyCodeSource( scriptCode, fileName, GroovyShell.DEFAULT_CODE_BASE );
        }
    } );
    GroovyClassLoader loader = AccessController.doPrivileged( new PrivilegedAction<GroovyClassLoader>() {
        public GroovyClassLoader run() {
            return new GroovyClassLoader( parentLoader, CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT );
        }
    } );
    Class<?> scriptClass = loader.parseClass( gcs, false );
```

That's was the expensive part. Now use `InvokeHelper` to bind the compiled code to a context (with global variables) and run it:

```
Binding context = new javax.script.Binding();
Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(scriptClass, context);
script.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly stolen from groovy.codehaus :

> The most complete solution for people
>   who want to embed groovy scripts into
>   their servers and have them reloaded
>   on modification is the
>   GroovyScriptEngine. You initialize the
>   GroovyScriptEngine with a set of
>   CLASSPATH like roots that can be URLs
>   or directory names. You can then
>   execute any Groovy script within those
>   roots. The GSE will also track
>   dependencies between scripts so that
>   if any dependent script is modified
>   the whole tree will be recompiled and
>   reloaded.
>
> Additionally, each time you run a
>   script you can pass in a Binding that
>   contains properties that the script
>   can access. Any properties set in the
>   script will also be available in that
>   binding after the script has run. Here
>   is a simple example:

```
/my/groovy/script/path/hello.groovy:

output = "Hello, ${input}!"
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;

String[] roots = new String[] { "/my/groovy/script/path" };
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(roots);
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("input", "world");
gse.run("hello.groovy", binding);
System.out.println(binding.getVariable("output"));
This will print "Hello, world!".
```

Found: [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy/)

Would something like that work for you?